# Get the list of activities from ResolveInfo

Tags: java, android, android-intent

The problem is that in a specific package, there are several activities that use a particular intent, I want the list of all these activities.

If I use

`infos.activityInfo.applicationInfo.className`

it gives me just the main activity or null.

Below is the example of what I'm getting:

```
09-11 04:46:31.628: I/User Interface(6779): name: Internet -com.android.browser.Browser
09-11 04:46:31.628: I/User Interface(6779): name: Internet -com.android.browser.Browser
09-11 04:46:31.628: I/User Interface(6779): name: Calendar -com.android.calendar.CalendarApplication
09-11 04:46:31.628: I/User Interface(6779): name: Calendar Storage -null
09-11 04:46:31.628: I/User Interface(6779): name: Calendar Storage -null
09-11 04:46:31.638: I/User Interface(6779): name: Camera -null
09-11 04:46:31.638: I/User Interface(6779): name: Cell Broadcast -com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver.CellBroadcastReceiverApp
09-11 04:46:31.638: I/User Interface(6779): name: Contacts -com.android.contacts.ContactsApplication
09-11 04:46:31.638: I/User Interface(6779): name: Contacts -com.android.contacts.ContactsApplication
09-11 04:46:31.638: I/User Interface(6779): name: Contacts -com.android.contacts.ContactsApplication
09-11 04:46:31.638: I/User Interface(6779): name: Contacts -com.android.contacts.ContactsApplication
09-11 04:46:31.638: I/User Interface(6779): name: Contacts -com.android.contacts.ContactsApplication
09-11 04:46:31.638: I/User Interface(6779): name: Contacts -com.android.contacts.ContactsApplication
09-11 04:46:31.648: I/User Interface(6779): name: EasyHome -com.lge.easyhome.LauncherApplication
09-11 04:46:31.658: I/User Interface(6779): name: File Manager -null
09-11 04:46:31.658: I/User Interface(6779): name: Gallery -com.android.gallery3d.app.GalleryAppImpl
09-11 04:46:31.658: I/User Interface(6779): name: Gallery -com.android.gallery3d.app.GalleryAppImpl
09-11 04:46:31.658: I/User Interface(6779): name: Home -com.lge.launcher2.LauncherApplication
```

You can see that multiple times the application name is popping but the activity is same. What does this mean? Am I correct in thinking that this intent is being used in multiple activities? If yes then is there a way to fetch all these activities?

Here is the code I have written.

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent();
    mainIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);        
    mainIntent.setType("text/plain");
    List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);

    int size = pkgAppsList.size();        
    Log.i(TAG, "Size: " + size);
    for(ResolveInfo info : pkgAppsList){

        String name = info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();

        Log.i(TAG, "name: " + name + " -" + info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.className);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  > Am I correct in thinking that this intent is being 
  > used in multiple activities?
```

An intent can **match** several activities. your example should list all

main-activity with a contentfilter contenttype "text/plain"

For a working example see method checkAndShowMatchingActivites() in [intent-intercept.. Explode.java](https://github.com/intrications/intent-intercept/blob/master/app/src/main/java/uk/co/ashtonbrsc/intentexplode/Explode.java)

Comment: infos and info was a typo. Corrected it. Sorry.